# Bootstrap 3 mobile menu with pull left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu

I'm using bootstrap 3, it all works fine on desktop. The drop down does it on roll over and the pull rights all look good.

Now when it comes to mobile the drop down breaks the layout as shows with scrollbars and the pull rights don't flow correctly.

Is there something simple im missing in the html to get this looking and working correctly?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/Product" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Brands <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="/Product/ProductList/5">brand1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Product/ProductList/2">brand 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Product/ProductList/7">brand 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="/Distributor">Distributor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/News">News</a></li>
                        <li class="pull-right navitem-blue">
                <a href="/Account/SignIn?returnUrl=%2FDistributor" id="linkLogin">Sign In</a>
            </li>

                    <li class="pull-right navitem-blue"><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be housing your right aligned links inside a new `ul` using `navbar-right` and you don't need two `navbar` types (as these are for styling), it should be `navbar-default` or `navbar-inverse`, not both. See [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment).

See working example Snippet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/Home/About">About Us</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="/Product" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Brands <b class="caret"></b></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li> <a href="/Product/ProductList/5">brand1</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="/Product/ProductList/2">brand 2</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="/Product/ProductList/7">brand 3</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/Distributor">Distributor</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="/News">News</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="navitem-blue"> <a href="/Account/SignIn?returnUrl=%2FDistributor" id="linkLogin">Sign In</a>

        </li>
        <li class="navitem-blue"><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact Us</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```